# How to create and update JSON file in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I just want to create a simple app which creates, updates, and deletes items in JSON file using AngularJS. I have looked online, only found examples which takes JavaScript objects to edit, or delete JSON type data. But I want to use JSON as backend in AngularJS.

Is there any examples out which can post data to JSON file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's the latest & greatest https://blog.backlift.com/entry/angular-tut1

Comment: Thanks Terry, but I'm not able to download example there and also is there anything which can edit/add .json file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('MyJsonService', function() {
  return $resource('/:myFile.json', {myFile: '@file'});
});
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.myJsonContents = MyJsonService.get({file: 'myFilename'}); // keep in mind that this is async though
```